# ST3 + Anaconda Python autocomplete useless suggestions

Tags: python, autocomplete, sublimetext3, anaconda

I am trying to configure ST3 as IDE for my Python development.

Here is a snippet of code:

```
from __future__ import division
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np
def main():
    ds = datasets.load_boston()
    x = ds.data
    y = ds.target
    x.ravel()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here are my Preferences.sublime-settings settings:

```
{
"color_scheme": "Packages/Theme - Flatland/Flatland Dark.tmTheme",
"theme": "Flatland Dark.sublime-theme",
"flatland_sidebar_tree_xsmall": false,
"flatland_square_tabs": true,

"auto_complete_delay": 10,
"auto_complete_triggers":
[
    {
        "characters": ".",
        "selector": "source.python - string - comment - constant.numeric"
    }
],

"font_size": 12,
"tab_size": 4,
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,

"caret_extra_bottom": 1,
"caret_extra_top": 1,
"caret_extra_width": 1.2,
}
```

Here are my Anaconda.sublime-settings

```
{
"anaconda_linter_mark_style": "none",
"anaconda_linter_underlines": false,
"suppress_word_completions": true,
"suppress_explicit_completions": true,
"enable_signatures_tooltip": true,
"merge_signatures_and_doc": true,
"pep8_ignore":
[
    "E305",
    "E309",
    "E501",
    "E112",
    "W291"
]
}
```

Here is list of all my installed packages:

- Anaconda (v2.1.10)
- Local History (v.2016.09.12.07.22.25)
- Package Control (v.3.2.1)
- SideBarEnhancements
- Theme - Flatland (v2016.11.07.16.37.27)

My issues are listed below:

1.) If I type **ds.** autocomplete does not suggest **data** or **target**, but they should be valid suggestions.

2.) If I type **ds.** autocomplete suggests suggestions like: from, if, def etc... I believe autocomplete scans through whole text file and adds suggestions from strings in it. Is there a way to disable that and make it suggest only relevant (functions, methods and member variables) suggestions?

3.) **x** is **np.array** type which has method ravel(). Once again, this method is not suggested. This is really not something I would expect from autocompletion.

Any help is much appreciated!
Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are known problems in Jedi (the library that anaconda uses to offer autocompletion) to complete NumPy and other scientific libraries. For example
https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/372

Complete list of non resolved issues about NumPy (probably some of them are duplicates): https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/search?q=numpy&state=open&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93

That is why you don't get completions for the NumPy arrays, to resume, currently anaconda can not offer you auto completion for NumPy because Jedi can not offer auto completion for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to add that I found a workaround which is pretty ugly, but might be of some use for someone else.

For snippet of code:

```
from __future__ import division
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np
def main():
    ds = datasets.load_boston()
    x = ds.data
    y = ds.target
    assert isinstance(x, np.ndarray)
    x.ravel()         # Autocomplete for x now works.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Autocomplete for numpy works after assert statement.

Seems like Jedi needs a little hint.

Comment: It will be probably a good idea to share that piece of information with David in here https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/372